# Outlook 2013 - set different signatures for different domain mailboxes

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-signature, signature

I have a domain exchange account on Outlook, and my exchange account includes several mailboxes.  If I go to the Account settings, only the primary email account shows, and it doesn't display the mailboxes here.

On the "Signatures" options, only the primary email appears, and the different mailboxes don't show up.  How can I set different mailboxes to automatically use a different signatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to all my research, and I've also spoken to an Office support specialist, and this is not possible in current versions of Outlook.  Maybe something to develop as an add-on or in future versions of Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the different mailaccounts in Account Settings, restart Outlook & then you can add a different signature for each defined mailaccount.